# How to add an I18N support to setup file made by the MSIX Packaging Toolkit

Tags: windows, msix

Could someone answer my question, please?
MSIX Packaging Toolkit creates a MSIX file, but with one language in the manifest.
Is there a way to add a few other languages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MSDN has a thorough explanation here: [Using MRT for converted Desktop apps and games](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/app-resources/using-mrt-for-converted-desktop-apps-and-games).

In a nutshell:

1. Create a bunch of XML files with your localized resources in them.
2. Change your manifest to use `ms-resource:///` strings instead of literal strings.

If you're using the Packaging Project then it should do all the work for you (no need to run all those command-line examples in the MSDN doc).